# How to create a dataframe from a nested dictionary using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested

I have the following nested dictionary:

```
dict1 = {'a': 1,'b': 2,'remaining': {'c': 3,'d': 4}}
```

I want to create a dataframe using pandas in order to achieve the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abcd'))
df.loc[0] = [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pop the `'remaining'` dict to update `dict1`, then convert the values to vectors (like lists).

```
nested = dict1.pop('remaining')
dict1.update(nested)

pd.DataFrame({k: [v] for k, v in dict1.items()})
```

```
    a   b   c   d
0   1   2   3   4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.json_normalize`:

```
dict1 = {'a': 1,'b': 2,'remaining': {'c': 3,'d': 4}}

df = pd.json_normalize(dict1)
df.columns = list('abcd')
```

Result:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
```